# Enable dropdown after typing all the values in textbox

Tags: javascript

In my HTML form, there are 2 textbox and one dropdown.

While loading the page, dropdown should not be editable(ie: disabled)

After filling all the textbox,the dropdown should be editable.

Please give an idea to solve this in javascript.

Comment: Can you share your html and what you've tried?

Comment: I didn't tried yet..i want logic to implement.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try like this

**HTML**

```
<input type="text" id="text1" onblur="myFunction()"> 
<input type="text" id="text2" onblur="myFunction()">
<select id="select1" disabled>
   <option>value</option>
</select>
```

**Javascript**

```
function myFunction() {
    if (document.getElementById("text1").value.length > 0 && document.getElementById("text2").value.length > 0) {
        document.getElementById("select1").disabled = false;
    } else {
        document.getElementById("select1").disabled = true;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Check both ***input*** elements value whenever *keyup* event is fired. If both the input elements have no inputs then disable the ***select*** element. Else enable it. Try this way,

***javaScript :***

```
function SetControlState(){
    for(var i = 0; i < inputs.length; i++){
        if(inputs[i].value.length == 0){
           selectddl.disabled = true;
           break;
        } else{
            selectddl.disabled = false;
        }
    }
}

var selectddl = document.getElementById("dropdl");
var inputs = document.getElementsByTagName('input');
var isEnabled = false;
for(var i = 0; i < inputs.length; i++){
    if(inputs[i].id == 'first' || inputs[i].id == 'second'){
        inputs[i].onkeyup = function(){
            SetControlState();
        };
    }
}
```

***HTML :***

```
<select name="ddl" id="dropdl" disabled="true">
    <option value="A">A</option>
    <option value="B">B</option>
</select>

<input type="text" id="first"/>
<input type="text" id="second"/>
```

[***jsFiddle***](http://jsfiddle.net/codeSpy/gsLtd9m8/)

Comment: Hey ! nice to see a bangladeshi here :)